# Display more than 100 entries through GraphQL API

Tags: graphql, github-api, github-graphql

I have tired pagination using endCursor and hasNextPage in github grpahQL API to get more than 100 data. Query I used is:

```
query {
      organization(login:"XXX") {
                   repository(name:"XX") {
                   pullRequests(first:100, states:[OPEN], after: "XXX" ) {
        pageInfo{
          hasNextPage
          endCursor
        }
      }
    }
```

It is working. But in order to access further details,iterative pagination needs to be done. Can anyone provides an efficient alternative to traverse all pages programatically in GraphQL API?

Comment: this is a limitation at the api level: https://developer.github.com/v4/guides/resource-limitations/. Nothing you do in your code can change that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pagination using endCursor is the one solution. Like REST API, you cannot traverse all pages pragmatically. As you specified you can specify endCursor and traverse if there is next page

Answer (score 4):

Taking inspiration from Simon Willison's '[Paginating through the GitHub GraphQL API with Python](https://til.simonwillison.net/github/graphql-pagination-python)' here's what I've been doing to paginate my queries:

```json
query {
  node(id: "PROJECT_ID") {
    ... on ProjectNext {
      items(first: 100 after: CURSOR) {
        pageInfo {
          hasNextPage
          endCursor
        }
        nodes {
          title
          fieldValues(first: 8) {
            nodes {
              value
            }
          }
          content {
            ... on Issue {
              number
              labels(first: 50) {
                nodes {
                  name
}}}}}}}}}
```

In my Python code I'm splicing in `PROJECT_ID` with a variable set to the project ID I'm referencing.

For the cursor `after: CURSOR` is replaced with `""` initially, and then for the next page I set `cursor = 'after:\\"' + response["data"]["node"]["items"]["pageInfo"]["endCursor"] + '\\"'`

My full code is in the [atdumpmemex](https://github.com/atsign-company/dump_cards/blob/main/atdumpmemex.py) module of my dump_cards utility.

The key here is to get `pageInfo` along with other relevant nodes, and then grab the `endCursor` each time `hasNextPage` is true so that it can be fed into the query for the next iteration.

pageInfo will look something like:

```json
"pageInfo": {
  "hasNextPage": false,
  "endCursor": "Y3Vyc29yOnYyOpHOAAhOsg=="
}
```

At the moment the `endCursor` is base64 encoded `cursor:v2:XYZ`, but don't rely on that as GitHub have moved other IDs from being base64 encoded to other schemes.