# How to search GitHub Projects Beta with GraphQL API

Tags: graphql, github-api

I've been playing with [Projects Beta](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/issues/trying-out-the-new-projects-experience) using GitHub's GQL API but can't find a way to filter / search / query them.

For instance, I'd to get all issues in a [project](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/reference/objects#projectnext) for which a [field](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/reference/objects#projectnextfield) has a specific value.

How do I do so? Is it possible?

None of those objects as a filter attribute.
I've also looked at the [search](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/reference/queries#searchresultitemconnection) query but that doesn't seem to support Projects or Fields as [query](https://docs.github.com/en/search-github/getting-started-with-searching-on-github/about-searching-on-github#types-of-searches-on-github) parmeters.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked about this in the [Projects Beta Feedback Discussion](https://github.com/github/feedback/discussions/5616).

It seems that filtering hasn't been implemented (yet) and so it's necessary to do things the old fashioned way (like with the REST API) by using queries to get all the issues, then filtering after.

In many ways this is worse than things were with the REST API, as there's no way to get just the issues in a given column, you have to get every issue on the board, which quickly then gets you into [needing pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49237159/display-more-than-100-entries-through-graphql-api/70039506#70039506).

At least GraphQL queries are specifying which nodes/fields you want back, so you're not having to filter through all of everything, just some of everything.

Comment: Is this still the same answer in 2023?

Comment: @tryforceful some of the naming has changed as `memex` and `projectsNext` has become `projectsV2`, but the underlying issue of no filtering has stubbornly persisted :(